# How to filter the OrderBy

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

i am retrieving data from database on the base of there id, as can be seen,

```
public ActionResult loadEpisodes(int id, string name, int epId)
{
     ViewBag.LoadEps = db.VideoEpisode
        .Where(ve => ve.VideoId == id && ve.IsActive == true)
        .OrderByDescending(c => c.Sequence);
    //some other code removed for the ease
     return view();
}
```

It will return the episodes of some 'id' and in descending sequence value.

My question is, if there is way to retrieve the data in descending order but order must starts from the episode id 'epId'

I have tried the above method but failed

```
ViewBag.LoadEps = db.VideoEpisode
.Where(ve => ve.VideoId == id && ve.IsActive == true)
.OrderBy(c=>c.Sequence)
.First(c=> c.VideoEpisodeId ==epId);
```

Comment: It's not clear what you want - can you give an example please?

Comment: you need to learn about models. the M in MVC. you should not use the ViewBag like this.

Comment: thanks for reply, the list i get from the databse is in descending order which is right ... i want the sequence as it is but the first value should be of id 'epId'....

Comment: So the returned values should be greater than `epId`? can you not just add `&& c.VideoEpisodeId >= epId` to the query?

Comment: Don't you just mean order by `VideoEpisodeId` and *then by* `Sequence`?

Comment: i mean it should be in descending order, except the epId which should be the first,,,,, i was doing wrong i know,,, thanks for reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: If I understand the problem correctly, you want the order to be a given episode with Id `epId` first, then a list ordered by sequence.

I'm not sure it can be done in one Linq query.

How about creating a new list, putting your chosen `VideoEpisode` in as the first element, and then appending a sorted list of the other episodes after that. Something like:

```
var Loadeps = new List<VideoEpisode>();
Loadeps.Add(db.VideoEpisode.First(c=> c.VideoEpisodeId ==epId));
Loadeps.Add(db.VideoEpisode
    .Where(ve => ve.VideoId == id && ve.IsActive == true && c.VideoEpisodeId != epId)
    .OrderByDescending(c => c.Sequence)).toList();
```